# Yup validation - determine if a field is required from validation schema

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form, yup

I'm using Yup validation in a React Typescript application. Based on the validation schema, how can I determine if a particular field is required? (I'm creating a custom text field component, and I want to dynamically add a `required` property if the field is required in the schema.)

Right now, I have:

```
import * as yup from 'yup';

const schema = yup.object().shape({
  name: yup.string().required('Required'),
  email: yup.string(),
});
const isNameRequired = schema.fields['name'].spec?.presence === 'required';
```

The problem is - I'm getting the following Typescript error on `spec`:

```
Property 'spec' does not exist on type 'Reference<unknown> | ISchema<string, AnyObject, any, any>'.
  Property 'spec' does not exist on type 'Reference<unknown>'.ts(2339)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this [.describe()](https://github.com/jquense/yup#schemadescribeoptions-resolveoptions-schemadescription)

```js
const schema = yup.object().shape({
   name: yup.string().required('Required'),
   email: yup.string(),
});
   

  function isFieldRequired(field) {
    return (
      schema
        .describe()
        .fields[field].tests.findIndex(({ name }) => name === "required") >= 0
    );
  }

  console.log(isFieldRequired("name")); // returns true
  console.log(isFieldRequired("email")); // returns false
```

Comment: Hmmm, on the `.tests` part, I'm getting the Typescript error "Property 'tests' does not exist on type 'SchemaFieldDescription'"

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a solution similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76149701/422845), but then simply **cast a few of the variables as `any`** (with an added `/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any */` at the top of the file). No matter what I tried casting to the "proper" way, it always ended up with another error, so I just decided it's not worth the headache, and that this should cause absolutely no issues, so I've proceeded using the following code with a clear conscience:

```
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any */
import * as yup from 'yup';

const schema = yup.object().shape({
   name: yup.string().required('Required'),
   email: yup.string(),
});

const isFieldRequired = (fieldName: string): boolean => {
  const field = schema.describe().fields[fieldName] as any;
  return field.tests.some((item: any) => item.name === 'required') ?? false;
};
```